# Change cursor VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, button, onclick, event-handling, mouse-cursor

I can't change the cursor when it's a ToolStripButton.click event.

I got 2 buttons that call "Rechercher".

EDITED : Only the Button is working. It seems that the ToolStripButton cancel my cursor...
Thx for the help

```
Public Class FenetrePrincipale

    Private WithEvents _btnRechercher As New Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton("Rechercher")
    Private WithEvents btnRechercherAccesBtn As New Button

    Private Sub Rechercher(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _btnRechercher.Click, btnRechercherAccesBtn.Click
        Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            'WAITING FOR THE CODE TO FINISH (2 sec)
        Finally
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It isn't the only difference.  The AccessBtn is setting the cursor *before* running the procedure.  Is there a `DoEvents` call anywhere in your procedure?

Comment: Maybe you should try with MsgBox("hello") in your sub to test the Event Handlers (to test if when you click something happens or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only way I got this to work.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Class FenetrePrincipale

    Private WithEvents _btnRechercher As New Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton("Rechercher")
    Private WithEvents btnRechercherAccesBtn As New Button

    Private Sub Rechercher(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRechercherAccesBtn.Click
        Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            'code...
        Finally
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub RechercherToolStripButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _btnRechercher.Click
        Me.UseWaitCursor = True
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, &H20, Me.Handle, New IntPtr(1))

        Rechercher(Nothing, Nothing)

        Me.UseWaitCursor = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should try something sampler like:

```
Private Sub MainFrame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Search()
End Sub

Private Sub Search()
Try
  Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
  UseWaitCursor = True
  Application.DoEvents()
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) 'WAITING FOR THE CODE TO FINISH
Finally
   UseWaitCursor = False
   Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
   Application.DoEvents()
End Try
End Sub
```

The problem is you don't have any pause where code should execute so it is doing to fast.

Comment: I don't hunderstand the use of a sleep. I'm gonna wait 1 useless second?

Comment: no but maybe your code which should do between try and finally is too fast done so you cant see the change. to test it if it works you can test it with sleep :) hope you understand what i want to say.

Comment: When the cursor is set, i'm waiting 2 second for my code to finish. When the event come from my toolstripbutton I can't change the cursor but otherwise it work.

Comment: It doesn't matter from where you click, is it button or toolstrip you always call Rechercher() or some other sub. Place Application.DoEvents() after the cursor change or any visual change you doing and it will work. The thing i set Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) is just for a test as a code could take 1 second to complete. You could try set this to 5000 then you will see the cursor.